# chrome extension storage: set/get value

Tags: google-chrome-extension, local-storage

Trying to set and get values in my Chrome extension using local storage. Don't know what I did, but it's no longer working.¨

In manifest I have:

```
   "permissions": [
      "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "storage"
    ],
```

This is the complete js, which sets a value and then tries to read it:

```
 chrome.storage.local.set({'userid': "foo"}, function (result) {
    chrome.storage.local.get('userid', function (result) {
        alert(userid.result);
   });
});
```

The alert says "undefined", not "foo" as expected.

The js is executed when i go to a certain page, specified in manifest for "content_scripts".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Doh, I figured it out. It should be:

```
alert(result.userid);
```

(reverse userid and result)

Comment: Thank you for the simple example of setting and getting a variable. It's taken me hours to figure out the freaking syntax.